# scipy and numpy inverse fft returns complex numbers not floats, can't save as wav

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, transform, fft

I am learning about Fourier transforms and how to use them in python for audio manipulation. But simply taking fft and ifft of audio data converts it into complex form and I am unable to save it as wav. The code and error are given below.

```
    import librosa
    import scipy
    audio,sr=librosa.load("sample2.wav")
    aud_fft=scipy.fft.fft(audio)
    ref_aud=scipy.fft.ifft(aud_fft)
    librosa.output.write_wav("test.wav",ref_aud,sr)
```

The error is

```
File "fft_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    librosa.output.write_wav("test.wav",ref_aud,sr)
  File "<decorator-gen-10>", line 2, in write_wav
  File "/home/vineeth/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py", line 58, in __wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vineeth/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/output.py", line 239, in write_wav
    util.valid_audio(y, mono=False)
  File "/home/vineeth/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 264, in valid_audio
    raise ParameterError('Audio data must be floating-point')
librosa.util.exceptions.ParameterError: Audio data must be floating-point
```

All I am doing is taking fft and then taking ifft of the output. It is supposed to come back to audio data right? Where am I going wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Please see the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.ifft.html - If you pass non real data to ifft, it returns complex numbers. So does fft.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much of a code problem as a mathematical problem.

A Fourier transform tries to extract the components of a complex signal. This signal can be a real signal or a theoretical one. As such, the Fourier outputs complex numbers with real and imaginary components to better describe the signal, in the range of -Hz -> +Hz. You want absolute values and a range of 0 -> +Hz for describing a real signal.

To constrain your data to real components, you need to do two things - find the absolute values of the complex data points and remove the negative Hz range (the second half of the FFT output array).

Try the following:

```py
import numpy as np

number_of_datapoints = len(audio)

complex_fft=scipy.fft.fft(audio)
real_absolute_fft = 2.0/number_of_datapoints * \
                    np.abs(complex_fft[:number_of_datapoints//2])
```

The juggling using `2.0/` and `//2` is due to an idiosyncrasy with odd and even arrays and the Fourier transform.

Edit:
It might be helpful to know your signal frequencies. You can calculate these with the `fftfreq` method, which only needs your sampling interval and data array length.

```py
time_interval = 1/sampling_rate
frequencies = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(number_of_datapoints, \
                                  d=time_interval)[:number_of_datapoints//2]
```

Comment: "The juggling using 2.0/ and //2 is due to an idiosyncrasy with odd and even arrays and the Fourier transform." Can you explain this more? multiplying with two increases the length of the list or doubles every value? I hope it is the former.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. If you have a 100Hz sampling rate, you can only infer frequencies unto the Niquist limit (1/2 sampling rate = 50Hz). What you get out at the end is actually an array of amplitudes from 0Hz --> +50Hz, and then -50Hz --> 0Hz.

Because you have a real signal and are only interested in the real components, you remove the second half of the array. A floor divide (//) makes sure you are selecting the real components inclusively, by "rounding down" the range.

If you're curious, try plotting the full range to see the whole array.

Comment: I'd also recommend checking out the documentation on the function here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html

If this has answered your question, could you please mark the post as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Just after your `ifft` function add `real` command
If you have a real signal (without imaginary parts), then the inverse FFT will give you a real signal too and you can run `real` command to withdraw the zero complex part.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, ifft        
sp = fft(fr)
# do some filtering/manipulation with your Fourier coeffs
# .....
# do inverse FFT
ifft(sp).real
```

But if you have a signal with complex parts, then omitting an imaginary part after IFFT will be incorrect.

It is interesting that `matplotlib` can draw a signal immediately after `ifft(sp)` command, in contrast, `[plotly][1]` can work only with real numbers `ifft(sp).real`